# UITextView next and previous Button over the Keyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextview

how can I implement "Next" and "Previous" Button's over the keyboard.
I use `UITextView` and with click on "Next" the Next TextView gets focus, Previous the last TextView.

I do not found any tutorial on the Internet.

I hope everybody can help me.

Comment: you can set a view with next and previous button as a textview's inputaccessoryView:..... and u can check this link .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954331/adding-uitoolbar-to-input-accessory-view-on-some-text-fields

Comment: OK thanks and how work this? Is the no "standard" function e.g. in safari you have also this buttons over the keyboard

Comment: Try to use this link. And i hope this will help you. 1. http://www.randomsequence.com/articles/adding-a-toolbar-with-next-previous-above-uitextfield-keyboard-iphone/ 2. https://github.com/0xced/XCDFormInputAccessoryView/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this custom control

[COCOA](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=BSKeyboard)

**If you need any help, let me know.**

This controlis very simple to use.

**Updated Answer**

**Change the Button Label**

Go to `BSKeyboardControls.m` file & make the following Changes

**On line no. 42**

```
 [self setSegmentedControl:[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[ NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"<", @"BSKeyboardControls", @"Previous button title."),
                                                                               NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@">", @"BSKeyboardControls", @"Next button title.") ]]];
```

**On line No. 51**

```
   [self setDoneButton:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Ok", @"BSKeyboardControls", @"Done button title.")
                                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                        target:self
                                                        action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)]];
```

/////  *******************  Update 2 ***************** ////////////
**SET Image for Previous & Next**

Just add the following code in `BSKeyboardControls.m` after line no. 52

```
    [self.segmentedControl setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:BSKeyboardControlsDirectionPrevious];
    [self.segmentedControl setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:BSKeyboardControlsDirectionNext];
```

Answer (score 0):

change `BSKeyboardControls.m` file & make the following Changes

remove this one

```
// [self setRightArrowButton:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:106 target:self action:@selector(selectNextField)]];
```

add this

```
        [self setRightArrowButton:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(selectNextField)]];
```